# Problema con While y factorial

Tags: java, while, factorial

Necesito saber porque esto me da valores incorrectos en Java.

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Ejemplo1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int factorial=1;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Digite un numero");

            int numero = sc.nextInt();

            while (numero!=0) {


                factorial=factorial*numero;
                numero= numero-1;

                System.out.print(factorial);

            }
```

Comment: El código funciona correctamente. El error te debe venir de otro sitio. ¿Que error te sale?. Usa el boton editar, para editar tu pregunta.

Comment: Que valor de número esta ingresando, ese deberia servir hasta 10 o 12 no creo que más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar recursividad para resolver este problema, acá te dejo el código.
Espero que te funcione.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Created by gonznake        
    System.out.println("Escribe un número:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int veces = sc.nextInt();
    int resultado = factorial(veces);
    System.out.println("El factorial de "+veces+" es: "+resultado);
        }

private static int factorial(int n){
    if (n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*(factorial(n-1));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, debía resolverlo con bucle while pero ya he encontrado la solución. Gracias.